# How to extract data using API and Python?

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I have a banch of servers and I use API to extract data about storage.
To get details about **storage uuid** (named storage in json) I use code as below:

```
srvdet = requests.get('https://hhh.com/1.2/server/76856585', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('login', 'pass'))
srvdet_json = srvdet.json()
datas = srvdet.json()
print(datas)
```

And result in json:

```
{
   "server": {
      "boot_order": "",
      "core_number": "2",
      "created": ,
      "firewall": "off",
      "host": ,
      "hostname": "hello",
      "ip_addresses": {
         "ip_address": [
            {
               "access": "private",
               "address": "",
               "family": ""
            },
            {
               "access": "",
               "address": "",
               "family": "",
               "part_of_plan": ""
            }
         ]
      },
      "license": 0,
      "memory_amount": "",
      "nic_model": "",
      "plan": "",
      "plan_ipv4_bytes": "",
      "plan_ipv6_bytes": "0",
      "state": "started",
      "storage_devices": {
         "storage_device": [
            {
               "address": "",
               "boot_disk": "0",
               "part_of_plan": "",
               "storage": "09845",
               "storage_size": ,
               "storage_title": "",
               "type": ""
  
}
```

For now it works perfectly fine. The problem is when I need to get **"09845"** which is value for **storage**. When I try to use this code:

```
for storage in datas['server']['storage_devices']['storage_device']:
    srvstorage = storage
    print(srvstorage)
```

The result is:

```
{'storage': '09845', 'storage_size':, 'address': '', 'boot_disk': '0', 'type': '', 'part_of_plan': 'yes', 'storage_title': ''}
```

What am I doing wrong? How to save "09845" in variable?

### EDIT:

Now I get error when trying to access details about storage.
I want to extract backup status which is **state** in json:

```
{
   "storage": {
      "access": "private",
      "backup_rule": {},
      "backups": {
         "backup": []
      },
      "license": 0,
      "part_of_plan": "",
      "servers": {
         "server": [
            ""
         ]
      },
      "size": ,
      "state": "online",
      "tier": "",
      "title": "",
      "type": "",
      "uuid": "",
      "zone": ""
   }
}
```

When I execute this code:

```
bkpdet = requests.get('https://fffff.com/1.2/storage/08475', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('login', 'pass'))
bkpdet_json = bkpdet.json()
datastg = bkpdet.json()
print(datastg)
for sts in datastg['storage']:
    bkpsts = sts['state']
    print(bkpsts)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The whole idea is to at the end get info about status using this code:

```
if bkpsts == "online":
    print('Backup has been created.')
else bkpsts == "backuping":
    print('Backup creation is in progress.')
else:
    print(bkpdet.status_code)
```

I was searching but still can't find what is wrong here.

Comment: I Guess you don't need this line  `datastg = bkpdet.json()` have you already parse it to json. Then replace `datastg` with bkpdet_json `.

Comment: I found the solution for edit part of my post is here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609001/error-when-trying-to-access-data-via-api-using-python/58613468#58613468>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a key when you want to access storage, you loop over it and it's fine. But in each iteration you get a dictionary from which you need to call the right key, in your case `storage`.

```py
for storage in datas['server']['storage_devices']['storage_device']: 
    srvstorage = storage.get("storage", None) 
    print(srvstorage)
```

## Note

`get` method will be preferable to use as you may encounter a device with out storage information inside, by using get you can avoid the `KeyError`.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: @Brzozova Perfect, feel free to validate this answer by clicking on the check mark button under the vote one.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
for device in datas['server']['storage_devices']['storage_device']:
    device_storage = device['storage']
    print(device_storage)
```